# Jenkins and GitLab: How to setup SCM aware job which is not triggered by the hook?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

To give some context the question is about GitLab and Jenkins setup.

I know how to setup a web hook, I know how to setup a job to be triggered by the hook. The problem is that I need to have multiple jobs and only a single entry-point (parent job) trigger for them.

The downstream jobs at the same time need to be git repo aware so I have to set repo url for them. This causes them to be triggered independently by the hook and I don't want that as this means that they are triggered twice.

On the other hand if I don't configure repo url on a downstream job and the parent job triggers it, it fails as it is not able to do a checkout.

I may try to hack around with some 'execute shell' build step, I believe it's not a valid way to go. Has anybody a good tip how to solve that?

For the reference here is the [GitLab Jenkins plugin documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-hook-plugin) according to which:

> Plugin will parse the GitLab payload and extract the branch for which
> the commit is being pushed and changes made. It will then scan all Git
> projects in Jenkins and start the build for those that:
>
> - match url of the GitLab repo
> - match the configured refspec pattern if any
> - and match committed GitLab branch

I tried playing around with different settings, without a great result though.

Comment: Can the downstream jobs run the checkout manually in a shell script?

Comment: The downstream jobs can also share the upstream's workspace so they don't need to do their own check-out.

Comment: @Fo. perhaps it can. It might be a wrong assumption but I thought it's the git plugin job to do the checkout, isn't it? There is always some maintenance pain added when jenkins grows with build logic relying on shell scripts. If there is no other option, well, whatever works...

Sharing sounds like an interesting concept which even might provide additional benefits I'm after. How would that work assuming I would like to spawn parallel downstream jobs. Each job on an own jenkins slave running on a separate machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the project you want to get only local triggers, just enable *Don't trigger a built on commit notification* in the *Additional behaviours* of git plugin.
(https://github.com/elvanja/jenkins-gitlab-hook-plugin/issues/11#issuecomment-35385032, as you actually have discovered).

But a better solution could be to make your downstream jobs reference the repository locally cloned by main job (not sure if actually possible), so the plugin will never consider them for schedule a build, as the git url don't match.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, this wasn't an obvious one as the Jenkins instance I tried to setup is so outdated the _Don't trigger..._ option isn't there.
Slaves for the downstream jobs are on different machines. Does reusing of repo make any sense in such circumstances?

Comment: If you cannot upgrade your jenkins instance, solution is difficult. And with slaves reuse of repository is hard. I expect to include a feature in next release that allows to specify a specific project in the gitlab webhook, but that feature is not yet ready. If you want to have a look, the proof is concept is on feature/project_trigger at http://github.com/javiplx/jenkins-gitlab-hook-plugin

Comment: Thanks, I meant it was tricky to find a solution while I was searching on the outdated Jenkins. Fortunately we'll be migrating to a new, quite up to date, one. So selecting "Don't trigger..." should do the trick.